# Why was hibernate's ClassMetadata.getIdentifier(Object, EntityMode) deprecated

Tags: java, hibernate, metadata, introspection

Just upgraded to hibernate 3.6.0 and found that this method is deprecated.

```
public Serializable getIdentifier(Object object, EntityMode entityMode) throws HibernateException;
```

It has been 'replaced' by this

```
public Serializable getIdentifier(Object entity, SessionImplementor session);
```

I'm not sure why this has been done, and more importantly, I don't believe the new method is a suitable replacement.

I have code which binds hibernate objects/properties by using this API to create hibernate objects from XML (attributes->properties etc) and some other bits and pieces too.

I have always considered ClassMetadata to be a public API that is to be used for this purpose.  And I have  been aware that SessionImplementor is an internal API that is not for use be application code.

Assuming I am correct in the above two assertions it seems wrong that a public API requires a private API as a parameter?

Does anyone know why this was done and how I should be approaching doing programmatic hibernate object access in the future?

(Interestingly the getting/setting property value methods still take an EntityMode.)

Answer (score 2):

I ask myself the same question. I have no idea why this was done, but now we need some dirty castings to use a public API. That makes no sense at all.